# Is there a way to plot a 2D curve from regularly distributed curvature values?

Tags: matlab, plot, curve

I have an array of regularly distributed curvatures, and initial conditions for gradient and starting point. I've got the original curve, defined discretely using cartesian co ordinates, but am looking at how we can reconstruct this shape from measured curvatures - does anyone know of a function that can be used to plot graphs from curvature?

Comment: It would be beneficial for the question if you added a sample of the data and some visualization of what the desired result (that is based on it) looks like.

Comment: Essentially I've got a plot, and in reality I'm going to be measuring the curvature at, say, 7 points. I've then used linear interpolation to find curvature between these plots and now I want to find the plot based on these curvatures so I can compare to the actual shape. Does that make a bit more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I managed to solve this using information from the following research paper: Multi-Core Optical Fibers With Bragg Gratings as
Shape Sensor for Flexible Medical Instruments by Fouzia Khan and co.